# Applet with image

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl

My main class (which extends applet) is showing an image with absolute path, but I don't know how to make it get the path from the folder where my html is.

```
    try {
        tutorial2 = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(
                new File("D:/eclipse/workspace/Final/res/tutorial2.png")));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Nu s-a gasit imaginea");
    }
```

But my html applet is in another dir, and I want when you move the html to still view the image.

Comment: You might find the [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) tutorial helpful

Answer (score 0):

Copy the image(tutorial2.png) and paste that image to the folder where you have saved the above class and then  do this

```
tutorial2 = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(
                new File("tutorial2.png")));
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: tutorial2.png (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Tanc.Game.setUpEntity(Game.java:1128)
 at Tanc.Game.gameLoop(Game.java:230)
 at Tanc.Game$1.run(Game.java:143)
Nu s-a gasit imaginea
Exception in thread "Thread-144" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Tanc.Game.INTRO(Game.java:858)
 at Tanc.Game.gameLoop(Game.java:266)
 at Tanc.Game$1.run(Game.java:143)

Comment: URL url = this.getCodeBase();
  String urls = url.getPath();
   System.out.println(urls);
/D:/work/t/bin/
Here is the image and it`s correct but my applet dosent see it.

Comment: which tool you are using to create your project(netbeans or eclipse)?

Comment: @user2979622 if you using any of the above tool paste that image in your project folder

Comment: eclipse , I resolved this , I`ll post the answer as soon as the website will allow me.

Comment: `URL url = this.getCodeBase();
  
String urls = url.getPath();

System.out.println(urls);
  try {
   tutorial2 = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(
     new File(urls+"tutorial2.png")));

  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.err.println("Nu s-a gasit imaginea");
  }`